# Reading a data from a buffer in C language

Tags: c

data  - >   Start address of the buffer to store the received data[here, received data is **hello**]

length ->   Size of the buffer

```
readfunction(uint8_t * data, size_t length) 

int main()
{
uint8_t ch;
readfunction(&ch , 1);
}
```

When I execute the program, ch is getting the first-byte 'data'[i.e., **h**]

and I am not able to read all the characters from data. How should I increment ch in such a way it would give me all the values[**hello**]

I tried incrementing the size of the buffer but I was not successful. Any method to do this?
Many, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an array. Not sure what you tried to increase the size of the buffer, but if I interpret your `readfunction` correctly, you'll want something like this:

```
uint8_t ch[6];
readfunction(ch , 6);
```

Note that the buffer space allocated is one greater than the amount of characters to be read, to account for the null-terminator of C-strings.
Also note that the first argument to `readfunction` is now `ch` rather than `&ch`, as an array is essentially a pointer to its first element (you could also pass `&ch[0]` instead).